# Bezier curve bevel is not round

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel

I am totally new to blender so sorry if asking something obvious but I am trying to model a tennis ball but not the easy way apparently... Meaning that I want to preserve the original shape of cover.

[See some math papers if interested](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262332580_Chaos_and_Graphics_Taiji_variations_Yin_and_Yang_in_multiple_dimensions)

But **when I try to duplicate the seam, then convert to curve, then bevel the curve (selected) I do not get circular shape but elliptical and cannot find the culprit.**

The selected curve is (2D) part of the whole curve (3D) because I wanted to test it on 2D curve.

My goal was to then subtract the beveled curve from ball to create that white rubber seam on tennis ball. So if you have a better approach or any other tips I would appreciate that.

[image]

Comment: Select the curve, press `Ctrl`+`A` > _Apply_ > _Scale_.

Comment: Wow, it worked! Thanks!